# SQL Query to fetch exact values

Tags: sql

I would like to know how to write query to fetch exact values from where clause. For example there is a table which has following data

```
USER    ACCESS
A       DEFAULT
A       EVERYONE
B       DEFAULT
B       EVERYONE
B       WEBACCESS
```

SQL query should be written in such a way that the output brings in only USER A . I have tried using group by and checking the count of records however it brought me both the users.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your question and show the table layout.

Comment: Okay, now the table data makes sense. But by what criteria shall your select statement decide that only user A is shown? Because there are exactly two records for user A? Or because there is no entry 'WEBACCESS' for user A? Or what else is the rule to be applied?

Comment: It should bring in users who have access to both EVERYONE and DEFAULT ONLY which in this case is user A  as user B has an additional access which is WEBACCESS so user B should not come in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are storing the information on different rows, and you are trying to "merge" the results for each user.  If so, you can do something like this:

```
select userid
from t
group by userid
having sum(case when access = 'EVERYONE' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when access = 'DEFAULT' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       count(distinct access) = 2;
```